# (401) Unauthorized Error when running reports for ssrs sql server 2012

Tags: reporting-services, unauthorized, reportserver

anyone got idea about this error? i got this error when trying to run reports in ssrs sql server 2012. but,they are working fine in sql server 2008 r2. is there any other configuration to be done in Reporting Service Configuration Manager or may be during installation of sql server 2012? for your information, i uploaded the reports to report server manually...if this action also might be the reason of this issue.

there are 5 options of sql server 2012 to be installed; BusinessIntelligence, Developer, Enterprise, EnterpriseCore, and web. I just installed Enterprise type. is this give any effect to reporting? i am not sure.

> An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
>   Query execution failed for dataset 'DataSet1'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand)
>   Failed to execute web request for the specified URL. Unauthorized: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. (rsXmlDataProviderError)
>   For more information about this error navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable remote errors

After enabling remote errors, it is saying that the credentials is invalid.

> 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied

i really need your help and idea to solve this issue. Thank you.

Comment: check all the parameters value and parameters name as well as check if you are using linked server then user must have the access of that database. You need to check very carefully as it's case sensitive. also check the dataset executing the query or not in sql profiler. still it doesn't help you let me know, I will help you. As I have also wasted so many time to solve such issue. Note: User must have to rights to that datasource.

Comment: the error is coming when deploying reports to new server.i have 3 different servers for web, services and database (reports located in database server). i think the authentication issue occurs when these servers want to connect to database server. but all the access have been provided...even trying to run report in local server also give the same error. this is really stressed me out, any ideas is very much appreciated...

Comment: hi...i did changes in Reporting Service Configuration Manager until getting error of

Comment: error:

`Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that <machineKey> configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.`

tried adding machineKey but no success.decided to delete Encryption Keys in the Conf Mgr and got this error:

`An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
The data extension supports Windows Integrated Security and No Credentials (anonymous request) only. (rsXmlDataProviderError)`

i need help..

Comment: ok...the previous error is because of all reports datasource gone missing. then i selected Windows integrated security, but the original error coming again.

`An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
Query execution failed for dataset 'DataSet1'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand)
Failed to execute web request for the specified URL. Unauthorized: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. (rsXmlDataProviderError)`
****
`Access is denied due to invalid credentials.You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied`

Comment: see, there must be some issue with access... you need to check more...